# Show/Hide a SpriteComponent using Flame in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flame

I am a beginner with the use of Flame, and I have a small problem.

My game has 3 states:

- Game is playing
- Game is paused
- Game is over

During each state, there should be different buttons displayed.
I use SpriteComponent to display my buttons, but I can't make elements "disappear" and reappear in the following functions:

```dart
// For example, I use this button 
// need to be displayed only during the pause state
PauseMenuButton pauseMenuButton = PauseMenuButton();

@override
Future<void>? onLoad() async {
  pauseMenuButton
      ..sprite = await loadSprite("btnFastForward.png")
      ..size = pauseButtonSize
      ..position = Vector2(size[0] * 0.3, size[1]*0.3);
  
  add(pauseMenuButton);

  if(gamePaused) {
      renderGamePause(canvas);
    } else if(gameOver) {
      renderGameOver(canvas);
    } else {
      renderGamePlay(canvas);
    }
}

renderGamePlay(Canvas canvas) {
    
 // hide pauseMenuButton
    
}

renderGamePause(Canvas canvas) {

  // show pauseMenuButton

}
```

Here is my SpriteComponent class :

```dart
class PauseMenuButton extends SpriteComponent with Tappable {
  @override
  bool onTapDown(TapDownInfo event) {
    try {

      print("back to menu");

      return true;
    } catch(error) {
      print(error);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

`onLoad` will only be called once when the game is loaded, so you don't want to have logic like this in there. Usually you want to have logic when an event happens or in the `update` method. In this case you probably want to do it when the buttons are pressed.

For hiding the `Component`s the easiest way is to simply remove them from the game.

You could create a world component that you add everything that is related to the actual gameplay in and then you can add the other screens, or buttons in this case directly in your game class.

So your game could look something like this:

```dart
class World extends Component with HasGameRef<MyGame> {
  @override
  void updateTree(double dt) {
    if(gameRef.isPaused) return;
    super.updateTree(dt);
  }
}

class MyGame extends FlameGame {
  PauseMenuButton pauseMenuButton = PauseMenuButton();
  late final World world;

  bool isPaused = false;
  bool gameOver = false;

  @override
  Future<void>? onLoad() async {
    pauseMenuButton
      ..sprite = await loadSprite("btnFastForward.png")
      ..size = pauseButtonSize
      ..position = Vector2(size[0] * 0.3, size[1]*0.3);
    add(world = World());
    world.add(Your game components);
  }
}
```

And then add `HasGameRef<MyGame>` to your `PauseMenuButton`, and when the button is clicked you just set `gameRef.isPaused = true` and remove any unwanted components from the game with `gameRef.remove(...)`.

There is a `SpriteButtonComponent` that you might want to extend for your button instead of `SpriteComponent`.

Comment: Ok thank you ! I will try this :)